# Youtube Flash API (AS3) not working in Firefox but in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash, firefox, youtube-api

I'm wondering why since very recently my own programmed flash-video-player (using the YouTube ActionScript 3.0 Player API) is not working anymore in Firefox (Win, 45.0.1) but it's working still fine in Chrome (Win, 49.0.2623.110 m).

The graphic elements of the video-player load fine in both, so the flash-plugin is working, but only Chrome shows the actual youtube-video.

I know the flash API is deprecated (https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference), but why is it still working in Chrome then? Any ideas of how I can get it to run in firefox again?

PS: Because of the complexity of the video-player and its function I cannot switch to the html5 version of the youtube-player-api.

**UPDATE:**

```
<object width="640" height="360" id="video" data="video.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
            <param value="video.swf" name="movie">
            <param value="xml=xml?i=48-96-43" name="FlashVars">
            <param value="high" name="quality">
            <param value="#181818" name="bgcolor">
            <param value="true" name="play">
            <param value="true" name="loop">
            <param value="window" name="wmode">
            <param value="showall" name="scale">
            <param value="true" name="menu">
            <param value="false" name="devicefont">
            <param value="" name="salign">
            <param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess">
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                <img alt="Get Adobe Flash player" src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif">
            </a>
        </object>
```

Comment: Do you have a test link online we can see?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's a project that isn't fully released yet. For the Future yes I guess we have to reprogramme everything in html5.

Comment: Okay. I just put a test SWF on my server. Does **[this link](https://vcone.co.uk/public/StackOverflow/Youtube_AS3_v2.swf)** play in your Firefox? Works for me...

Comment: Your example works perfectly and you also use the embed-tag.

Comment: I actually use the object-tag, could that cause the problem?

Comment: My example is a direct link to the SWF file (no html embeding involved). I understand your problem now though. Mine just loads the standard YTube player within AS3 app, I just tried a "found" chromeless SWF from some tutorial and that does **not work** in Firefox. I'll see if there's a possible fix later today...

Comment: In your code you're using the official youtube-iframe right? Only your iframe-src-url requests the embedded-player (&feature=player_embedded) right? I think that's different than in our case programm a swf that is using the API.

Comment: Yes you're right. We typed at the same time. Like I said I'll look into it when I'm on the Flash IDE later. If you just need the video file only, there are (unofficial) ways to get MP4 directly from YT server. That should be a last resort though

Comment: PS: In the **[API demo page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)** If you choose type : **Flash + Chromeles Player** and hit "update player" it doesn't work first time but click "update" again and now it will auto-play. Dunno if it's a bug in Firefox? (remember Chrome works fine)

Comment: That's another site I found where the videos in the player will not play  in Firefox but Chrome: http://www.innovativedesigns.org.uk/#/Video%20gallery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a **[chromeless Youtube SWF working in Firefox](https://vcone.co.uk/public/StackOverflow/Youtube_Chromeless_v1.swf)**.

The short answer is... Make sure your SWF file is being served from an `https` location. If there is no (SSL) green padlock, the SWF will not load up any other external data. This seems to be a new (security) expectation by Firefox for Flash content that tries to access further external data.

Also update any `http://` references in your AS3 code to become `https://`.

Examples would be :

- `Security.allowDomain("https://www.youtube.com");`
- `loader.load(new URLRequest ("https://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3") );`
- `player.cueVideoByUrl("https://www.youtube.com/v/YOUR_VID_ID?version=3");`

Comment: Hi VC.One, now my video-player is not working in any browser.Do you have any further workaround? The loading bar of the video stays at 0%.