# External swf loaded from link doesn't work in some browsers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox, flash-cs6

I'm developing a game that due to its extension needs to load external swf. This game is on some flash portals and loads these external swf from urlrequest and loader. Some browsers like Chrome or Opera are loading these external swf totally fine, but I'm having problems with Firefox (and I'm not totally sure if also with Microsoft Edge). **ALL** players that are running the game on Firefox can't load the external swf from the link (http address).
I have the "allowDomain" and "allowInsecureDomain" correctly added in both (main and external) swf files.

Which is the problem? Firefox security settings with external http addresses? Is there any way to solve it?

Any help will be appreciated!

Edit: this is the code I used:

```
//on the 1st frame of my main .fla
import flash.system.Security;

Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");

//on the frame I want to load the external file

var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
var bytesLoaded;
var bytesTotal;
var scene01:MovieClip;
var percentLoaded:Number = bytesLoaded/bytesTotal;

function progressListener (e:ProgressEvent):void{
trace("Downloaded " + e.bytesLoaded + " out of " + e.bytesTotal + " bytes");
percentLoaded = Math.round(percentLoaded * 100);
}


ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadfile);
ldr.load(new URLRequest("http://img110.xooimage.com/files/e/7/e/external_file.swf"));

ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressListener);

function loadfile(e:Event):void {
scene01 = MovieClip(ldr.contentLoaderInfo.content);
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadfile);
addChild(scene01);
scene01.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you could post the markup you're using to load the SWF.

Comment: Are you listening for errors when you use the `Loader`?   If so which errors are you recieving?  Network Error?  Security Error?  IO Error?  You should listen for all those error events when loading with the Loader class.

Comment: I edited and posted the code. Hmm.. I don't know how to listen for errors. Is it like "trace" an error? Sorry, I've never done it before. If so, is it possible to debug it online? When I debug it on flash it works perfectly. The problem is just firefox

Comment: Firefox expects a Flash app hosted on an **https://** server to only load external files from an `https://` location. This might be linked to your issue. There is **[same behaviour when using Youtube API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36618114/2057709)** which loads an external player SWF interface.

Comment: Thanks! It's what I expected. So I suppose I need to host my external content on https addresses to make it work in all browsers