# Flash AS3 read proxy server response with URLLoader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, urlloader, urlstream

I am running an embedded flash 'swf' inside a LAN network with a proxy server. Proxy server interrupts some urls and returns my usage information. I am trying to access this information by sending those urls. I can see this traffic in firebug ,But the URLLoader does not seem to read it. Neither Complete event or progress event get fired. I tried URLStream with a timer also,but availableBytes were always zero.Is it possible to read this information?

```
  private var getLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  private var sendRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
  public function XDomain() {
   sendRequest= new URLRequest("requesturl");
   getLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, eventHandler);
   getLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,eventHandler2);
   getLoader.load(sendRequest);
  }
  private function eventHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("running");
  }
  private function eventHandler2(event:ProgressEvent):void {
   trace("runninhg progresss");
  }
```

Thanks in advance //
**Edit:** I had this security error

```
[SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048"]
```

Comment: Please listen to SecurityErrorEvents and HTTPStatusEvents and lets see what it says.

Comment: @Jacob HTTPStatusEvent  listner is blocking my code.Is there something I am missing? //getLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, httpHandler);// .trace after this does not run.

Comment: _"URLStream with a timer"_ why??? Is there a result if you let it work naturally, without a timer interrupting? URLStream is your best bet since it gives raw access to server response. If still failing, show your URLStream code or give testable link that re-produces your issue.

Comment: None of the events were firing that is why i used a timer to return getLoader.bytesAvailable .I guess it wont do anything.

Comment: About events you have an `import flash.events.*;` in your code? Does it help to add that? The _not running_ `trace` is inside httpHandler function right?... Anyways `URLLoader` itself isn't going to show you any server's response text. Show me how you instead tried `URLStream` (short example, testable in our own compilers). I'm seriously struggling to **not** make it work in my own tests so either your URLStream code is wrong or else share an example/testable link to the crazy server.

Comment: Thanks again.In the above example itself If i replace URLLoader with URLSream that is a minimal example of my setup. I have  trace functions for getLoader.bytesAvailable inside the progress event. but those are irrelevant without the event actually getting fired.//  Yes i do  already have // import flash.events.*;//

Comment: `sendRequest= new URLRequest("https://www.google.com");` does that URL at least get some progress event firing? For _Google.com_ I got four lots of your `runninhg progresss` showing (in Flash IDE) when using your code with URLStream as a replacement. Also your first line of code.. `getLoader:URLLoader() = new URLLoader();` should be `getLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();` If you got no error showing here then I wonder if same issue is responsible for no traces in  other parts of code?

Comment: Also because it's URLStream so trace the incoming data like this : `trace(event.target.readUTFBytes(event.target.bytesAvailable) );`

Comment: URLLoader() was a typo.//I dont get progress events for google.com . Flash requests https://www.google.com/crossdomain.xml and retrieves it .But it shows the error again not revealing the data . I am compiling it with wonderfl.net  and running in firefox on linux. // I have a setup a server with a crossdomain.xml for testing. which works perfectly i can make GET and  POST requests successfully . I think that shows code part is fine.// About event.target part ,since I have defined getLoader with a 'new'  isn't it available directly without using event.target (Anyway it doesn't matter ).

Comment: See if [**this Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476683/youtube-flash-api-as3-not-working-in-firefox-but-in-chrome/36618114#36618114) makes sense to you somehow. I think Firefox expects both your swf and the contacted server to be running on `https`, if both sides are not matching (`http` or `https`) then it will block your swf accessing any data. I also never compiled with Wonderfl.net (maybe using a website brings its own new issues)... PS: `new` is just new unique instance of something, `event.target` is to say whichever object (target) has this `eventListener` attached...

Answer (score 0):

> *"But the URLLoader does not seem to read it..."*

Use `URLStream` (without a timer, cos what does that even achieve?) to reach the link and inside your related progressEvent use a `readUTFBytes` to get any text response data given by that link's server. Use progressEvent to also check size of any received bytes (the event fires multiple times, getting 64kb packets, until full data is downloaded).

**about Error #2048:** 
`URLloader` is a decoder for visual data (jpg, png, swf, text) but for non-text data it expects a **crossdomain.xml** to exist at the other server you are accessing the swf from (both sides must also have a matching same `http` or `https`. Again best way to by-pass this is to just load the bytes into a byte array (via URLStream but the progressEvents now should write to your byte array) then later use `URLLoader.loadBytes( yourSWFBytes );`

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Events does not  fire with URLStream either .I get the same security error too.

Comment: _"Events does not fire"_ Then there is **no connection** at all. _"I get the same security error too"_ False, there isn't a security issue when decoding your own bytes. There isn't even an issue to fill those bytes by `readBytes` from any external server. That's why its an **actual workaround**. By the time you use `getLoader.load(myBytes);` that `load` is told to decode your own image bytes, if instead you give some external URL (like that `sendRequest`) then you force it assume you're stealing content so it has security error when not finding permissions file existing at external server.

Comment: [**`Edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41331039/edit) your Question showing an example of how you handle URLStream, Bytes and Decoding process. Both your above conditions are unknown in that system. PS: So if URLStream is not running (no progress detected) then how do you later get the security error? Did the bytes size match the swf file size before you tried to decode (display) with URLLoader? Anyways I'll look at your code if you update...

Comment: I have embedded the swf on an html file.The network panel shows me connection and response from the server.I can see the Get request and response from the server .The network responds but flash for some reasons(security may be) does not accept the data( I guess) .//Complete event and progress event does not fire ,but security event does fire and gave me the response error 2048.bytesize is always zero both totalsize and availablesize.  Thanks

Comment: The actual request flash makes is a server/crossdomain.xml . But the server will respond with usage information along with an error message. I am looking for the information part in there.

Comment: I hear you but... **(1)** The only way to get such info via AS3 code is using the URLStream API since that handles any data sent by server. **(2)** You "record" the received bytes by copying into some bytearray using a **progressEvent**, which you say doesn't fire once and so with that issue you could never do steps 1 or 2..  **(3)** URLLoader's `load` command is for **decoding image formats** (or SWF), it is the wrong tool if you don't expect to load valid bytes for some jpg, png or swf. **(4)** URLLoader strangely also checks source URL of loaded content to see if you have rights to display.